# Deserialization of sometimes string and sometimes object with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to parse this type of JSON data to java objects:

```
{"id": 1, "blob": "example text"} 
{"id": 2, "blob": {"to": 1234, "from": 4321, "name": "My_Name"}}
```

I am using Gson, and don't know how to get around this particular problem, of "blob" sometimes being a string and sometimes an object.

Comment: Yech! Can you change/fix the format now?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. You mean if I could manually change the layout of the JSON?

Comment: Do you need blob": "example text value?

Comment: Yes, I need so I can both have a situation where blob is a string, and another situation where blob is an object.

Comment: @user1090614 If "need" is really "would like" - i.e. is not a requirement of a silly external API or interface that cannot be changed - then the downright *best* solution is to fix the structure such that it is unified *or* where the types diverge by key.

Comment: @user2864750 But that is not my question. I am not in control of how the data is produced or the structure of it - therefore its not an option to just fix the structure.

Comment: @user1090614 Create a custom [TypeAdapter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) then. You can use GSON's POJO mapping again internally (using the supplied Reader) once you have determined the correct type. This method will result in unifying as a *wrapped* type (that which said TypeAdapter was created for).

Comment: I already have the unsung hero badge ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution to your problem is to write a `TypeAdapter` for your class, however if you have *only* cases like that in your example, you can achieve the same result letting Gson do the job for you using the most generic class you can for deserialization.

What I mean is shown in the below code.

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19478087;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q19478087 {

    public class Test {
        public int id;
        public Object blob;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test [id=" + id + ", blob=" + blob + "]";
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] str){
        String json1 = "{\"id\": 1, \"blob\": \"example text\"}";
        String json2 = "{\"id\": 2, \"blob\": {\"to\": 1234, \"from\": 4321, \"name\": \"My_Name\"}}";

        Gson g = new Gson();
        Test test1 = g.fromJson(json1, Test.class);
        System.out.println("Test 1: "+ test1);

        Test test2 = g.fromJson(json2, Test.class);
        System.out.println("Test 2: "+ test2);
    }

}
```

and this is my execution:

```
Test 1: Test [id=1, blob=example text]
Test 2: Test [id=2, blob={to=1234.0, from=4321.0, name=My_Name}]
```

In second case, blob will be deserialized as a LinkedTreeMap, so you can access its elements using `((Map) test2.blob).get("to")` for example;

Let me know if it's enough or if you are interested also in the type adapter solution.

Comment: I wrote that blob will be deserialized as a `LinkedTreeMap`, so you can access its elements using `((Map) test2.blob).get("to")` for example. Maybe it was not so highlighted since I forgot code formatting. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Your POJO

```
class FromToName{
    String to;
    String from;
    String name;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FromToName [to=" + to + ", from=" + from + ", name=" + name
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Your conversion code

```
  String json ="{\"id\": 1, \"blob\": \"example text\"}"; 
  //String json = "{\"id\": 2, \"blob\": {\"to\": 1234, \"from\": 4321, \"name\": \"My_Name\"}}";
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonElement element = gson.fromJson (json, JsonElement.class);
  JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
  JsonElement id = jsonObj.get("id");
  System.out.println(id);
  if(jsonObj.get("blob") instanceof  JsonPrimitive  ){
         JsonElement blob = jsonObj.get("blob");
         System.out.println(blob);
   }else{
          FromToName blob = gson.fromJson (jsonObj.get("blob"), FromToName.class);
          System.out.println(blob);
   }
```

If you have any doubt in this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Take that as a JSON Element and then use isMethods() to figure out the type at runtime.

[Documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html)

```
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement ele = jp.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject().get("blob");;

            if (ele.isJsonObject()) {
                  //do related stuff here
            } else if (ele.isJsonArray()) {
                  //do related stuff here
            }
```