# How to deserialize String or Object using gson

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a json list that looks like this :

```
[{
        "status": "ok",
        "message": "session info updated"
    }, {
        "status": "ok",
        "message": {
            "screen_touch": 0,
            "digest": "19e526518975818cd76b580b7760358de56c18fd",
            "screen_dpi": 24,
            "agent_key": "",
            "machine_id": "",
        }
}]
```

and my java POJO's :

```
public class Response implements Serializable {
    String status;
    Message message;
}
```

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
    int screen_touch;
    String digest ;
    int screen_dpi ;
    String agent_key;
    String machine_id ;
}
```

when i try to parse the json using gson , it doesn't work because i don't handle the case where the json field message is a string :

```
Response[] response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response[].class);
```

being new to gson could anyone please help me find a way to deserialize this , maybe a CustomDeserializer ?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481958/7574461

Comment: how do you expect it parse it two different message types onto message? its java.

Comment: You could define message as an object. Possibly.

Comment: It works when i define message as an object , but in this case i don't see a way to store message values as a java object

Comment: What would you do with the string value? Your problem is that you get two different objects with the same name. Definitely you need a custom deserialiser. Or you can have it as an object and check if it is a `String` or a `Map` and decide, after mapping with Gson, what to do with each.

Comment: Would it make sense to split `Response` into two subclasses? For example `StringMessageResponse` and `ObjectMessageResponse` (you can probably choose better names). With your current design it is not clear how the String `message` could be represented as `Message` object.